# Ionic 3 show loading symbol on http request

Tags: ionic-framework

I am learning Ionic,so once the Signup button is clicked, How to show loading symbol and hide it after getting the reponse in ionic 3 ?

sign.html

```
<button ion-button color="danger" block outline (click)="signup()">Signup</button>
```

signup.ts

```
signup() {
    this.authServiceProvider.postData(this.userData, "signup").then((result) => {
    this.responseData = result;
    console.log(this.responseData);
    if( (JSON.stringify(this.responseData._body)) != "" ) {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
    } else {
        console.log("User already exists");
    }
    }, (err) => {
        //connection failed error message
        console.log("something went wrong");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to **import** loading controller.

```
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
```

in the **constructor**, you need to create an object of it. as

```
constructor(public loadingCtrl: LoadingController){}
```

Now before calling the service in signup method, you need to activate loading message and after the result, dismiss it.

```
signup() {
 let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Please wait...'
    });
    loading.present();
    this.authServiceProvider.postData(this.userData, "signup").then((result) => {
    this.responseData = result;
    console.log(this.responseData);
    if( (JSON.stringify(this.responseData._body)) != "" ) {
     loading.dismiss();        
     this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
    } else {
        loading.dismiss();
        console.log("User already exists");
    }
    }, (err) => {
        //connection failed error message
        console.log("something went wrong");
    });
}
```

Comment: @deepak let me know in case of any issue.

Comment: thank, this solution works, and am getting white screen on please wait.. How to remove that ? https://imgur.com/Ah0SovN