# How to use ion-loading in http get request and response?

Tags: angular7, ionic4

I'm create Ionic 4 angular app, and i'm use http get and response back.
now i want to ion-loading when request and response.below i'm paste this solution link which is available in ionic 3 but i want in ionic 4 ?

[Ionic 3 show loading symbol on http request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50582422/ionic-3-show-loading-symbol-on-http-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [spinner dialog](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/spinner-dialog) instead.

Comment: Ok @sourabh sir, Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

import **Loading Controller**

```
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
```

in the **constructor** create an object

```
constructor(
    private loadingController: LoadingController
) {}
```

Try as follows.

```
async presentLoading() {
    const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
      message: 'Please wait...',
      translucent: true,
    });
    return await loading.present();
  }

homeData() {
    this.presentLoading();
    this.dataService.getData().subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.loadingController.dismiss();
    });
}
```

See official docs [ion-loading](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/loading)